# How to use ngTagsInput to filter data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I have code that will expand on a search, but I need help with narrowing down.  An example would be adding tags (color, green) and having only "color green" show up and not all the colors and the arm.

Here is my example: http://codepen.io/stvgale/pen/vxzBXO

```
app.filter('filterByTags', function () {
return function (items, tags) {
if (!tags || !tags.length) {
  return items;
}

var lowerTags = angular.copy(tags);
angular.forEach(lowerTags, function (tag) {
  tag.text = angular.lowercase(tag.text); 
});

var filtered = [];
(items || []).forEach(function (item) {
  var matches = lowerTags.some(function (tag) {
    return (angular.lowercase(item.data1).indexOf(tag.text) > -1) ||
           (angular.lowercase(item.data2).indexOf(tag.text) > -1);
  });
  if (matches) {
    filtered.push(item);
  }

});

return filtered;
};});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex

Join your tags array to get a search text

```
var searchtext = lowerTags.map(function(elem){
        return elem.text;
    }).join(" ");
```

For example if you your tags are `color,green`

the `var searchtext` would be `color green`

and then you can just use this text as regex pattern to check which items match

```
var patt = new RegExp(searchtext,'i');
```

and return the matched items

```
var filtered = [];
    (items || []).forEach(function (item) {
      var matches = lowerTags.some(function (tag) {
        return patt.test(item.data2);
      });
      if (matches) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }

    });

    return filtered;
```

Here is the **[FULL Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/k1537j0d/10/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The only problem with this is that if you do      green, color nothing shows up.

Comment: You can reverse the string and match with regex, but that would become ugly. I recommend changing you JSON structure.